# Can I get Spring's <context:property-placeholder /> to tell me what classpaths it's looking in?

Tags: java, spring, classpath

We have this line in our Spring `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
```

But it's not finding and substituting particular property value which we think it ought to be. Is there any way for us to make this particular property-placeholder tell us the paths it's looking through, the files it's looking in and the properties it's seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`, something like this:

```
public class LoggingPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void setLocations(final Resource[] locations) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
            for (final Resource resource : locations) {
                logger.debug("Using resource: " + resource);
            }
            super.setLocations(locations);
    }

    @Override
    protected Properties mergeProperties() throws IOException {
        final Properties mergedProperties = super.mergeProperties();
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
            for (final Entry<String, Object> propertyEntry :
                new TreeMap<String, Object>((Map) mergedProperties).entrySet()) {

                logger.debug(
                    "Key:" + propertyEntry.getKey()
                + ", value:" + propertyEntry.getValue());
            }
        return mergedProperties;
    }

}
```

Now wire your custom class manually (namespace won't work):

```
<bean class="path.to.LoggingPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations" value="classpath*:*.properties" />
</bean>
```

And set your logging configuration so that log level debug is active for `LoggingPlaceholderConfigurer`

(This is meant to be a temporary replacement for `<context:property-placeholder>` for debugging purposes only)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you can get the current classpath by calling `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`

Answer (score 0):

you could attach spring framework sources into your project and using debugging, you could see which property files are found/read. I think it is a project configuration/packaging/deployment problem. try to make a copy of your property file, say my.properties and put into one of the packages and see if it is working. If it works, then you need to re-configure your classpaths.